# SpriteKit - Contact detection on multiple objects

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have one platform in the middle with two circles.

One circle at the top. One circle at the bottom.

When the bottom circle touches the top of the screen I want to write an NSLog message.

When the top circle touches the bottom of the screen I want to write an NSLog message.

I have set circle1 and 2 to have categorybitmasks and contactTestBitMasks. Any test I do, I can only find when the top or bottom circle have hit the bottom of the screen, but cannot work out how to detect when the bottom circle has touched the top. I've started my if statement

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
// If the top circle touches the bottom edge
 if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bottomEdgeCategory) {
    NSLog(@"This is the top ball touching the bottom edge");
 }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift ClassCastException when SKPhysicsBody.node -> SKLabelNode. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316484/swift-classcastexception-when-skphysicsbody-node-sklabelnode-why)

Comment: See the duplicate question: SpriteKit reports contacts in arbitrary order, so either `bodyA` or `bodyB` might be your bottom edge. Also, watch out for Starscream.

Comment: I've seen that, and it doesn't provide an answer for me in this scenario unfortunately (otherwise i wouldn't have posted). What i'm confused about is having two circles and two edges. Which is which? How can you detect contact on those?

Comment: Ha, cheers! ;) I want to detect if the top circle hits the bottom of the screen and if the bottom circle touches the top of the screen. Being new to SpriteKit (today) i'm curious to know how to achieve this with just bodya and bodyb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Sprite Kit, please read the following tutorial regarding collision detection.

This shows the code for having one sprite contact another.  What you would do is create a thin rectangle sprite along the top of the screen and another along the bottom.  Assign them different contact bit masks.  Using the code from the following tutorial, add a contact event for hitting the topOfScreenSprite and the bottomOfScreenSprite.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

My preferred version:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask==circle1Category && secondBody.categoryBitMask == topOfScreenCategory)
    {
        NSLog('c1: Top Hit');
    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask==circle1Category && secondBody.categoryBitMask ==    bottomOfScreenCategory)
    {
        NSLog('c1: Bottom Hit');
    }       
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask==circle2Category && secondBody.categoryBitMask == topOfScreenCategory)
    {
        NSLog('c2: Top Hit');
    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask==circle2Category && secondBody.categoryBitMask ==    bottomOfScreenCategory)
    {
        NSLog('c2: Bottom Hit');
    }   
}
```

Note: firstBody will always be the category that has the lower value assigned to it.

Comment: Meisernman - Thank you so much for taking the time to respond so thoroughly. :)

Comment: My pleasure.  I remember starting out... once you get the hang of contact and collision your possibilities are endless.  Trust me, you are basically at that point :)  It doesn't get much more complicated